# Checking column exists with If else condition in sql

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql5

I'm trying to check weather thw column exists or not

```
IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'tb_consumer' AND COLUMN_NAME='businness_id' > 0 ) THEN 
 PRINT 'test'
```

Whats wrong with above sql? getting error as

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IF (Select COUNT(*) From INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS Where TABLE_NAME = 'tb_consu' at line 1

New to SQL. Thanks for any help,

Version of MySql is 5.X

Comment: do you try this inside a stored procedure or as part of a normal query?

Comment: @Olli A normal query. Not in SP.

Answer (score 4):

You can fix the query by moving the closing paren:

```
IF (SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'tb_consumer' AND COLUMN_NAME = 'businness_id'
   ) > 0 THEN 
 PRINT 'test'
```

A better way to write the condition is using `exists`:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1
           FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
           WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'tb_consumer' AND COLUMN_NAME = 'businness_id'
          ) THEN
```

Comment: My version not supporting IF EXISTS.

Comment: Why on earth these both queries throwing error to me :(

For query 1  the error message is : `Error Code: 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IF (SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    WHERE TABLE_NAME = '' at line 1`

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ . . . In MySQL, the `if` statement is only allowed in code blocks, such as stored procedures, stored functions, and triggers.  Because you asked the question, I assumed the code was in such a code block.

Answer (score 1):

SQL command is not a Boolean function. 
Therefore you need to check the value.

Like this:

```
IF (SELECT COUNT(*) 
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
    WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'tb_consumer' AND COLUMN_NAME='businness_id') >= 0 
THEN PRINT 'test'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you try to use this as part of a stored procedure, you might take a look at [the if statement in the mysql documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/if.html)

if you do this as part of a normal query, you can write it like

```
SELECT IF (COUNT(*) > 0, 'TEST, 'TEST FAILED') FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'tb_consumer' AND COLUMN_NAME='businness_id'
```

Answer (score 1):

i would suggest using CASE statement in MYSQL

```
SELECT CASE 
    WHEN COLUMN_NAME = 'businness_id' then 'TEST'
    END
    from FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
    WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'tb_consumer'
```

Case statements are faster on smaller databases